How can the cmaketools extension find the visual studio kits automatically in my device?
After install the cmake tools extension on my vscode, and my windows computer already has the visual studio 2022 but the extension can not find the visual studio's kits automatically
I have tried to find many solution in the Internet, it can just recognize my mingw, while with the mingw-gcc it can not configure properly, it still has error, so I tend to try the visual studio, and it cannot work too.
